# INSERT INTO query not working in Express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm having trouble inserting data into a MySQL database. Select queries work fine, so I'm assuming that it's something stupid that I've missed, either in the Express code, or, in my HTML. The page I'm running the query from is located at `localhost:8080/add`, and I'm trying to `INSERT INTO`.  Here's my code:

**Javascript**

```
app.get('/add', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/Views/add.htm'));
});

app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    var fName = req.body.fName;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var id = req.body.id;
    var post = {id: id, user: fName, email: email};
    console.log(post);//This holds the correct data

    connection.query('INSERT INTO user VALUES ?', post, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Successfully added information.');
        } else {
            console.log('Was not able to add information to database.');
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML is simply a submit button and 3 input fields, within in a `POST` method form. Again, I can connect to the database and read from it with a select query, I just cannot insert into it.

Comment: `VALUES (?)`  Needs round brackets and I would have thought `VALUES (?,?,?)` if you are inserting 3 columns

Comment: But if you are using parameter substitution a prepare is also probably required

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just edited my question to further explain my problem, hopefully it'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation here **https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values**.

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Successfully added information.');
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            console.log('Was not able to add information to database.');
        }
});
```

Valid mysql statement is `SET` instead of `Values`.